# Old iTextSharp version not exporting non-English PDFs

Tags: c#, itext

I am using `iTextSharp version 4.1.6.0`. I am exporting text in multiple languages (Chinese, Russian, Korean). However, I am not able to write to `PDF Documents` like I can with English text.

How do I get it done with this version of `iTextSharp?`

I don't want to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Stacktrace? Exception? Error? Sample code?

Comment: I am not getting any error, simply i found the text is missing for these languages

Comment: Well.. if you could not provide any details.. this question could be closed soon..

Comment: Hi kasim, The problem is when i wrtie something in chinese language, it is not giving any error, the pdf is opening. the Problem is where ever the the chinese language has to be there, i am seeing white space. it is not throwing any erros.  the problem is it is not able to write the characters to PDF, it is simply ignoring the text.  i am not sure, guess that there are issues with unicode characters.  because the problem with chinese, russian, korean, greek languages only

Comment: You should upgrade. Significant improvements have been achieved in newer versions. Asking *How do I get it done with this version of `iTextSharp`* isn't a real technical problem. The only answer that makes sense is: *You don't, please upgrade!* What else did you expect?

Comment: You cannot really do it. iTextSharp comes with release notes. If your version states it does not support something, it does not.

Comment: yes, i am able to do this by supplying the font.ttf file and using this to create fonts. we have to explicitly supply the required font that supports the characters we want to display in PDF file.   var basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALUNI.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); and when ever the font has to be specified say new Font(basefont, 12, Font.BOLDITALIC, Color.BLACK)